# Pandas Dataframe - reducing number of columns (destructuring data)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like this, tracking sales by country:

columns:

Day,          USA, MEXICO, CANADA

"2020-01-01", 5,   10,     15

"2020-01-02", 10,  15,     20

But I would like to reduce the number of columns to make it a bit easier to work with:

Hopeful Output:

Day,          Country, Sales

"2020-01-01", USA    , 5

"2020-01-01", MEXICO , 10

"2020-01-01", CANADA , 15

Is there an easy way of doing this?
My current thoughts are to create three separate dataframes:
df1: Day, USA
df2: Day, Mexico
df3: Day, Canada

and then concatenate them one by one:

df_new = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis = 1, sort =False)

df_new_new = pd.concat([df_new,df3]), axis = 1, sort = False)

The reason I'm asking here is that I thought there would be an easier way, and hopeful to find out if there is an official term for this sort of "destructuring" of a datatable/df.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `melt` function. In this case:

```
df_new = df.melt('Day', var_name='Country', value_name='Sales')
```

See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html